# Проблема с PHP MyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Привет всем! Есть базы, в базах таблицы, хочу сделать экспорт таблицы выдает вот такую хитрую вещь:

```
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Z:\home\localhost\www\Tools\phpmyadmin\libraries\export\xls.php on line 5
```

Что это помогите? как вытащить мне таблицы с phpmyadmin кроме как экспорт или как исправить ошибку?

Comment: Что не понятно из сообщения об ошибке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здравствуйте, ошибка глосит что файла Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer.php - не найдено скриптом. Проверьте его наличия если нет, попробуйте скачать другую версию phpmyadmin. Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо помогло!

Comment: Обращайтесь)